# change dateformat of jquery datepicker

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

Here is my Code and it returns date in different format than I actually need .

```
var date2 = $('#txtDatePicker').datepicker('getDate');
        alert(date2);
        date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + parseInt($('#noOfDays').val()));
        date2 = date2.toString();
        date2 = date2.substring(0, date2.indexOf('00'));
        date2.trim();
```

I want to display this format in my textBox but behind the scenes I want to send date format like this 24/07/2014

had tried

> altFormat

even then not able to do ????

Somewhere i m going wrong ... not sure what ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
var date2 = $('#txtDatePicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }).val();
alert(date2);
```

More [Details dateFormat](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)

Or

```
var dateObject = $("#txtDatePicker").datepicker("getDate"); // get the date object
var dateString = dateObject.getDate() + '/' + (dateObject.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + dateObject.getFullYear();// dd/mm/y format
```

## [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakmanwal/5sVpA/2/)

Answer (score 1):

Try **[`dateFormat`](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-dateFormat)** option,

```
var date2 = $('#txtDatePicker').datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' }).val();
```

Or

```
var date2 = $('#txtDatePicker').datepicker('getDate');
date2 = $.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', date2);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tpN6M/3/)**

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/tpN6M/1/. Works for me. How and where are you getting the value?

Comment: not working .... I want to display different format in textbox and want to fetch format 'dd/mm/yy' ....

Comment: actually I have specified dateFormat: "DD, d MM, yy" while defining datepicker to the textbox.... but now i want to fetch value in 'dd/mm/yy' format .....

Comment: Can you specify the format you want to show in `textbox`? What is not working? Check the console to see correct format. Can you post the whole code in the question

Comment: $('#txtDatePicker').datepicker({
                dateFormat: "DD, d MM, yy",
                minDate: 1,
                maxDate: "+5M",
                onClose: function () {
                    UpdateCheckOut();
                }
            });

Comment: function UpdateCheckOut() {
            var date2 = $('#txtDatePicker').datepicker('getDate');
            alert(date2);
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate() + parseInt($('#noOfDays').val()));
            date2 = date2.toString();
            date2 = date2.substring(0, date2.indexOf('00'));
            date2.trim();
            $('#refreshCheckOutDate').empty();
            $('#refreshCheckOutDate').append("<br />" + date2 + "");

        }

Comment: k n thnx 4 a quick helping hand